# CKEDITOR 5 - Add custom dropdown to toolbar

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am using CKEditor 5 (Superbuild). How can I create custom dropdown button and clicking on dropdown item, selected item should insert inside editor.

[image]

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/eb5axy97/)**

```
<div id="rpCkEditor">Some text here...</div>

CKEDITOR.ClassicEditor.create(document.getElementById("rpCkEditor"), {
  toolbar: {
    items: [
      'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor'
    ],
    shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true
  },
  placeholder: '',
  removePlugins: [
    'CKBox', 'CKFinder', 'EasyImage', 'RealTimeCollaborativeComments', 'RealTimeCollaborativeTrackChanges', 'RealTimeCollaborativeRevisionHistory', 'PresenceList', 'Comments', 'TrackChanges', 'TrackChangesData', 'RevisionHistory', 'Pagination', 'WProofreader', 'MathType', 'SlashCommand', 'Template', 'DocumentOutline', 'FormatPainter', 'TableOfContents', 'PasteFromOfficeEnhanced'
  ]
});
```

Comment: You never showed any efforts, but only general configuration. I'd advise to start with examples in the framework like `StyleUI` or `FontFamilyUI`.  There you will find some things like `createDropdown()` which you can all lookup in the API: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_ui_dropdown_utils.html#function-createDropdown. Of course you can start just with a copy and adjusting the details. Then you can ask about distinct problems if this is not working.